# Format linq query output for a grid

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, linq, telerik-grid

I want to format results form my linq query and pass it to a grid.
I have Weeks first date(Date on Monday) as my input with which I pull data for that week(Monday through Sunday.

Here is what I have stored in DB, which is being pulled via linq query:

```
   Date        Hours
07/29/2013      1.3
07/29/2013      2.0
07/30/2013      3.1
07/31/2013      0.1
07/31/2013      5.2
08/01/2013      1.1
08/01/2013      1.1
08/01/2013      2.2
08/02/2013      3.3
08/02/2013      4.0
08/03/2013      2.1
```

Here is how I want to display the output in grid:

```
   Day        Hours
Monday         2.3
Tuesday        3.1
Wednesday      5.3
Thursday       4.4
Friday         9.5
Saturday       2.1
Sunday         0.0
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[GridAction]
public ActionResult GridOutput(string dateOnMonday)
{

 DateTime DateOnMonday = Convert.ToDateTime(dateOnMonday);

 var WeeklyHoursToGrid = (from h in db.vwHours.Where(h.Date >= DateOnMonday && h.Date < DateOnMonday.AddDays(7))
    select h.Hours).Sum();

    return View(new GridModel { Data = WeeklyHoursToGrid });

}
```

HTML(Grid):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<UI.Models.vwHour>>" %>

<div>

<% Html.GridFor("WeekDetails", "GridOutput", "Hours", GridOptions.EnableSelecting, Model).Columns(column =>
        {
            column.Bound(o => o.Date).Title("Day");//Display Day's instead of Date
            column.Bound(o => o.Hours).Title("Hours");//Display Total Hours for that day
        }).Render();
%>

</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Such my question give me many negative reputation, I couldn't explain anyone my problem what is. Everybody said that use string format:(

Comment: Could you use o.Date.ToString("ddd");? it convert 1 day to mondey

Comment: @ElvinArzumanoğlu Yes, that worked for displaying the date

Comment: I write it as answer, if it works for you, can you mark the answer as accepted. :)

Comment: Thank you. I am blocked, so I need many\ reputations.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Model that will allow you to manipulate the Date before sending it to the view

```
//Model
public class WeekData{
 public string DayOfTheWeek{get;set;}
 public decimal Hours{get;set;}
}
```

Send the Data inside a IList to the view
To set the DayOfTheWeek use Date.DayOfWeek.ToString()

Answer (score 1):

you can use **o.Date.ToString("ddd");**. it convert 1 day to mondey

Comment: Are your able to column.Bound(o => o.Date.ToString("ddd"))??